# CMake + ninja - exe file shows no output if header file is included in a source file

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

I am learning to use CMake and I'm using ninja as a build system. I have created a very simple program, but I have one issue. I have only two files `main.cpp` and `constants.h`. Whenever I include `constants.h` in `main.cpp`, after building a .exe file, I see no output from it after running it through bash. When i remove the include, it works just fine. Can anybody please guide.
**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "constants.h" // does not even show output when i add this

int main() {
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

**constants.h**

```
#pragma once
const int WIDTH = 1000;
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMIPLER "g++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")

project(BoidSimulation)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(BoidSimulation main.cpp)
```

Can someone please guide what I'm doing wrong. I have tried to add `constants.h` in `add_exectuable` and also used `target_include_directories` by keeping the header file in some directory.
I build and run through the following commands:

```
cmake -G "Ninja" -S . -B ./out/build/
cd out/build
ninja
./BoidSimulation
```

Running this with header file shows no output and no errors on bash, it just moves on to next line. It runs fine through powershell and shows the output with or without header files.

Comment: yes, i tried with different directories too, it doesn't work either ways.

Comment: I made this as minimal reproducible example. I had other header files as well, none of them would work.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. What build type is this? Release? Debug? What do you see when you do a diff of the two built executables- one from where you don't include the header, and one from where you do?

Comment: I have edited and explained the complete behavior in my question as well.

Comment: You didn't address my clarifying question on what build type this is and what you see when you diff the executables with and without the included header. Please do that.

Answer (score 0):

You never print a newline. In some shells this will cause the prompt to be printed over it. This has nothing to do with your constants.h header.